# Add custom "upload image" option on contact page

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration, image, custom-options, contact-us

I want to provide a special service to my customers which require an option to upload image on contact page just below or above the message area. Can it be possible ?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

**step1:** `add an input  of tye file to contact us page.` at contacts/form.phml

```
<input type="file" name="customerimg"  value="" />
```

**Step2:** `rewrite contacts us indexController.php  and  code for uplaod image to post action`.

**How to override controller check the link**
http://www.amitbera.com/how-to-override-a-controller-in-magento/

you code at postAction  look like

```
    public function postAction()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        if ( $post ) {
            $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
            /* @var $translate Mage_Core_Model_Translate */
            $translate->setTranslateInline(false);
            try {
                $postObject = new Varien_Object();
                $postObject->setData($post);

                $error = false;

                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['name']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['comment']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['email']), 'EmailAddress')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if (Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['hideit']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                    $error = true;
                }
        /* add file type vliadatio  */
            if (isset($_FILES)){

        if ($_FILES['customerimg']['name']) {
                        $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'modulename' . DS .'amit'.DS;
                        $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('customerimg');
                        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','png','gif'));
                        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
                        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                        $destFile = $path.$_FILES['customerimg']['name'];
                        $filename = $uploader->getNewFileName($destFile);
                        $uploader->save($path, $filename);

        }
    }

                if ($error) {
                    throw new Exception();
                }
                $mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
                /* @var $mailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */
                $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
                    ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
                    ->sendTransactional(
                        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
                        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
                        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT),
                        null,
                        array('data' => $postObject)
                    );

                if (!$mailTemplate->getSentSuccess()) {
                    throw new Exception();
                }

                $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');

                return;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            }

        } else {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        }
    }

}
```